# Inline comment editing issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, inline-editor

Before I click on *edit* on the comment to [an answer to *Basic PHP problem, code won't run! (no errors just blank)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866828/basic-php-problem-code-wont-run-no-errors-just-blank/6866837#6866837) I see:[image: comm]

After I edit the comment, the following comment suddenly appears, but it still says `add / show 1 more comment` (cannot get a screenshot because I am out of my 5 minute limit.)

---

New example: [an answer to *Should I remove static function from my code?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676515/should-i-remove-static-function-from-my-code/7676633#7676633)

[image: step 1]

---

[image: step 2]

---

[image: step 3]
^^^What is going on there?

Comment: It would be good to know _what_ suddenly appears.

Comment: @Hendrik -- lol I left out the word `comment` sorry about that

Comment: But it's still hard to help you since we don't know _what comment_ suddenly appears. If you write "the following", then something should follow.

Comment: @Hendrik.. the comment that would be seen if one would click on `add/show 1 more comment`

Comment: @HendrikVogt see update ^_^

Comment: what web browser -- why are you seeing add/show for questions that have *less than five comments?* That already should not be happening and does not happen for me in Chrome (current ver). Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @JeffAtwood this is Chrome 14.0.835 And this is the 2nd time I have seen this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit an edit to a comment, the server returns *all* comments on the post, and the JavaScript displays them, even if some of the comments were hidden previously. What wasn't taken into account so far is that "add / show" then has to be turned into "add", since there's nothing more to show.

This hasn't come up before because a) it's exceptionally rare that someone edits a comment when some comments are hidden (usually it's not even possible), and b) except for an unnecessary AJAX call and confusing wording, this wasn't really a huge issue, hence chances were good of it going by unnoticed.

The next build fixes this. Thanks!